# US wife visiting me in the UK - what to tell the immigration officer?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, spouses

I am an Indian national currently residing in the UK. My wife is a US citizen.  She will be visiting me in the UK soon. What should she tell the immigration officer?

Does she tell him/her that we are married? She has never worked and has nothing to her name. I am obviously happy to look after her expenses. In terms of her ties back home - she has her med school interviews and the fact that I intend to move there next year (we have a letter from USCIS stating that they are now processing our application ). I have a letter from my employer declaring I work for them and my annual salary. I am also giving her a letter to say that I am inviting her and I will take care of her expenses while she is here.

Will this be adequate? What should she say to the officer? Will saying that she is visiting be adequate? We are just a tad nervous because she only went back to August 14th.

Comment: `we are married` That is the best reason for her regular visits. And as you are married, it is expected you will take care of her expenses while she is in UK. Else the border agent will be very suspicious.

Comment: Is your wife travelling on a US passport? Or alternatively, what passport is she travelling on?

Comment: Absolutely tell them you're married. If you withhold that information, then they find out later, you'll be in trouble.

Comment: She is travelling on her US Passport

Comment: If she is a US citizen, why are you so worried? I mean, won't she get a visa on arrival (if she even needs one) for a casual visit with her family? Am I missing something?

Comment: Our worry is that she needs to convince the officer at the immigration desk that she intends to leave the UK in the end and she is not 'living' in the UK. She has already been in the UK twice this year and she is neither actively studying nor working. She has no assets to her name. She has nothing really strong tying her to the USA - so no real motivation to return to the USA even though she fully intends to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Telling the truth that your are married is correct and after giving the invitation letter and salary certificates. I don't think there wont be any issue at all. If possible, if you have marriage certificate, there are no chances to question your wife anything thereafter.

Answer (score 4):

So the advice here worked out fine for us. My wife is back in the country now. However for future reference - as a visitor a US citizen cannot spend more than 6 months within a 12 month period in the UK unless they have a valid Visa. I am now starting the process to get my wife a residence permit in the UK.

Comment: cool. If you have immigration visa questions, expats.stackexchange.com may be able to help you out on those too.